# Training a computer for word auto-segmentation (non-english language)

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-segmentation

I have been given a set of 80 non-english words in an excel file..the first column contains the resulting word after a crude automatic segmentation has been applied to it and the second column contains the resulting word after being segmented manually. Below is a set of 3 rows of the file

Auto segmentation  .........    Manually segmented

1. [%D-Ik--(is$)    ...........   [%D-Ik]--(is$)
2. [%D-Ip-t-eR]-(u$)   ....          [%D-I]-[pt-eR]-(u$)
3. [%D-Om-(a$) ...........       [%D-Om]-(a$)

My question is: is there a way with which I can train a model with this set of examples in order to segment new words (that start from d) automatically?

Comment: It is a sequence labeling problem. For every character in the sequence, you want to assign a flag if it is an end of a segment. 80 examples are however too few to any machine learning.

Comment: Perhaps I can ask for more data. Seting that aside, is there a particular algorithm that would be the most appropriate for this task (e.g. hidden Markov model)?